# Linked list headers

Tags: list, links, header

I'm trying to make a sub page where I have multiple link lists. Each of the links would need to open up a new window into either a web page or a document. Right now, I can't find a way to add sub headers to each of the lists. The different lists don't have to be linked together, I just need a share point page that contains multiple lists with a header detailing what the list is as below

Hardware
  --Link1
  --Link2
Software
  --Link1
  --Link2
Settings
  --Link1
  --Link2